# Is django a restful api?

Tags: django, rest

I am confused. Some say it is a Restful API and some say it is not.

How do we define a RESTful API? GET,PUT,POST and DELETE commands ?

Can I call any web application which is built using django Web framework a Restful API?

Comment: REST is just a concept. You can build RESTful APIs with any framework. I suppose if you want to build completely restful webservice then django-rest library would be best

Comment: What are the constraints to become a RESTful API?

Comment: [This paper](https://github.com/Microsoft/api-guidelines/blob/vNext/Guidelines.md) from microsoft has details about REST APIs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I am confused. Some say it is a Restful API and some say it is not.**

Two different kinds of Django:

1. Django - a web application framework to rapidly develop web applications
2. Django REST Framework (DRF) - a powerful framework to create RESTful APIs.

Both framework are in Python.

**How do we define a RESTful API? GET,PUT,POST and DELETE commands ?**

You create an API on your backend application that defines its purpose. If you use DRF for example, and the URL of your API is yourdomain.com/customers/, you can have it to:

1. return all the customers information by implementing GET method
2. create a customer information by implementing POST method
   ... and so on

**Can I call any web application which is built using django Web framework a Restful API?**

You call it as backend

Answer (score 0):

Django is a web framework to create web backend while REST (REpresentational State Transfer) is an architectural style for developing web services.
You can use django to create REST apis.
You can explore further here: 
**Django:** https://www.djangoproject.com/ 
**REST:** https://youtu.be/llpr5924N7E

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from the web is here:

- It should have some commands like PUT, GET, POST and DELETE etc., commands
- The URL of the API should be user/machine understandable
- It should have OAuth secret key and token for each client to access from his
  application.
- The URL should be www.api.xyz.com. But I am not sure about it to have `api` in the URL. Can someone confirm it?

And few more constraints to be a RESTful API. Hope all these points are correct.